# Is there any way I can debug the war deployment process of the tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat is deploying a A war but not the B war, both the wars consists of same servlets and configs

I have two wars, that is A and B both of them consist of same servlets, to differentiate them I have added the id attribute in the web-app tag also the display-name is unique in the web.xml which is present in the war file. I copy paste this war file in my webapps folder (autodeploy is true) and my tomcat is running , it deploys the A war but the B war only consist of logs folder. I did go through the logs of tomcat which is present in the catalina/logs/catalina.log but I didn't find any exceptions there.

When I rename my B war to A and vice versa, tomcat deploys both of them correctly with all the files present inside the folders. I know that tomcat deploys the wars alphabetically, so just renaming the wars might solve the problem but I can't do that as I have to change my production URL's.

Comment: What do the logs say? Tomcat should write log statements to `catalina.out` (or stdout if you are running Tomcat using `startup.sh` or similar) each time an application is deployed. Are there any errors, etc.?